# get_post_meta in woocommerce email notifications

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to get some data from an order in a woocommerce email template, but get_post_meta just returns false.  This code works on the thankyou page.  I have spent too much time on this.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

```
global $post;

echo "test!!!<br />";
$x = get_post_meta( $order->id, 'attendee_data', true );
$y = get_post_meta( $order->id, 'attendee_test', true );
echo $order->id . '<br />';
echo $x;
echo $y;
```

I've attached a picture of the sql as well as an email.

SQL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUFBa.png

Email: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uqtih.png

The whole email template:

```
<?php do_action('woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading); ?>

<p><?php _e( "Your order has been received and is now being processed. Your order details are shown below for your reference:", 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text ); ?>

<h2><?php echo __( 'Order:', 'woocommerce' ) . ' ' . $order->get_order_number(); ?></h2>

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid #eee;" border="1" bordercolor="#eee">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php _e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <th scope="col" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php _e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <th scope="col" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php _e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php echo $order->email_order_items_table( $order->is_download_permitted(), true, ( $order->status=='processing' ) ? true : false ); ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <?php
            if ( $totals = $order->get_order_item_totals() ) {
                $i = 0;
                foreach ( $totals as $total ) {
                    $i++;
                    ?><tr>
                        <th scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee; <?php if ( $i == 1 ) echo 'border-top-width: 4px;'; ?>"><?php echo $total['label']; ?></th>
                        <td style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee; <?php if ( $i == 1 ) echo 'border-top-width: 4px;'; ?>"><?php echo $total['value']; ?></td>
                    </tr><?php
                }
            }
        ?>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<?php
global $post;

echo "test!!!<br />";
$x = get_post_meta( $order->id, 'attendee_data', true );
$y = get_post_meta( $order->id, 'attendee_test', true );
echo $order->id . '<br />';
echo $x;
echo $y;
foreach ( $x as $k => $p ) {
    echo $k ." ... ". $p;
}  ?>

<?php // attendee_order_details($order->get_order_number()) ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text ); ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text ); ?>

<h2><?php _e( 'Customer details', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

<?php if ($order->billing_email) : ?>
    <p><strong><?php _e( 'Email:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></strong> <?php echo $order->billing_email; ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($order->billing_phone) : ?>
    <p><strong><?php _e( 'Tel:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></strong> <?php echo $order->billing_phone; ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php wc_get_template( 'emails/email-addresses.php', array( 'order' => $order ) ); ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer' ); ?>
```

Comment: what is in line 56 of `customer-processing-order.php`?

Comment: It would probably be better to hook to the `woocommerce_email_after_order_table` action instead of modifying the template.

Comment: You might try removing `global $post` since you are using `$order`...

Comment: @doublesharp I am using a hook, but switched to this for testing.  Additionally, I have tried with/without post.

Comment: @Dez That is me attempting to loop through an array that `get_post_meta( $order->id, 'attendee_data', true )` should return.  Excuse the sloppiness.  This is just for testing.

Comment: True won't return an array. True will only return a single result as a string.

Comment: I'm storing an array, not attempting to get all meta with the same key and id.  Check the sql pic.

Comment: When and where are you adding this custom meta to the orders? What kind of code do you use for that? Are they extra form fields or something added automatically in the checkout process? @rnevius

Comment: @birgire : The field is added to the checkout page via the `'tlcommerce_after_order_notes'` hook (using a standard `woocommerce_form_field()`). On submit, the order meta is then updated with `'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta'` (using a standard `update_post_meta()`). This is properly saving data to the database, as I'm able to see it in the database and admin (using `get_post_meta( $order->id`)...however, `get_post_meta()` returns an empty result when called from the email template for this meta value.

Comment: My use case is not so different from the OP's. If his question can be answered, so can mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some testing based on your info and tried to reproduce your problems.

First I created a function which inserts the post meta (attendee_test and attendee_data) when placing an order (using the `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta` hook like you do).

I added this in my themes `functions.php` (Note that the values are based on your input (image from db) and are not dynamic, just for testing):

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'add_meta_values', 2);

function add_meta_values($order_id){

    // array with attendee data
    $attendee_data = array(
        array(
            'edit' => 'false',
            'company' => 'get',
        )
    );  

    add_post_meta( $order_id, 'attendee_data', $attendee_data );
    add_post_meta( $order_id, 'attendee_test', 'test' );

}
```

Then I added the following code to the template `customer-processing-order.php`:

```
<?php

$attendee_data = get_post_meta( $order->id, 'attendee_data', true );
$attendee_test = get_post_meta( $order->id, 'attendee_test', true );

echo 'Order ID: ' . $order->id . '<br />';
echo 'Attendee Test: ' . $attendee_test . '<br />';
echo 'Attendee Data:<br />';

foreach ( $attendee_data as $k => $data ) {

    foreach ($data as $key => $value){

        echo $key . ' .. ' . $value . '<br />';

    }

} ?>
```

As you can see I modified it a bit to make it more clear. Also changed the $attendee_data loop because I think that wasn't completely right (needed an extra foreach). Of course this isn't related to the real problem.

Making a testorder will show the following data in the email:

[image: Data in order confirmation email]

This result demonstrate that `get_post_meta` is working in the email template based on the code above. (I used Wordpress 4.0.1 and WooCommerce 2.2.10).

If the test above is working fine also in your case then I think that the values are inserted in your database **after** the email is sent (they are inserted right, but to late).

Another thing you might want to check is resending the confirmation email. You can do this from the Wordpress admin. When you edit an order you have a dropdown 'Actions' on the right side. You can select 'Processing order' under 'Resend order emails'. Then click the refresh icon next to the dropdown and you will receive the order confirmation email again. See screenshot below:

[image: Resend order confirmation email]

This time you know for sure the values are already in the database before you're sending the email.

Hope this information is helping you to solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Well, 'attendee_data' is a serialized object so the third argument passed on the function get_post_meta  must be set to false (or omitted).

```
$x = get_post_meta( $order->id, 'attendee_data', false );
```

Comment: This is wrong. As mentioned [in the docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta): 

`The third argument, if set to true, will return a single result, as a string. If false, or not set, then the function returns an array of the custom fields. This may not be intuitive in the context of serialized arrays. If you fetch a serialized array with this method you want $single to be true to actually get an unserialized array back. If you pass in false, or leave it out, you will have an array of one, and the value at index 0 will be the serialized string.`

Comment: indeed, with this method he will get an array within other array with index 0. But this is kind of weird because attendee_test is working but not attendee_data.

Comment: `attendee_test` isn't working either. The only things showing in the email are from `echo "test!!!<br />";` and `echo $order->id . '<br />';`...unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Non, it's me that is missing something... I thought that the "test" was the echo of attendee_test (that the value is 'test').
In this case I think that we can try to use get_post_custom or try to access the custom field like : $order->attendee_data or simple dump the $order and see if the object is out there.